# ERROR_NOACCESS on WriteMemoryProcess

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the money adress to change to whatever i want , but when i try doing so i get 998 error which is ERROR_NOACCESS . I have visual studio ran as administrator.

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "PC Building Simulator");
    if (hWnd == NULL)
    {
        cout << "App not found" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD proccess_ID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &proccess_ID);
        HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, proccess_ID);
        if (hProcess==NULL)
        {
            cout << "App not found" << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            int newdata = 500;
            DWORD newdatasize = sizeof(newdata);
            WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)0x1B13B498FB0, &newdata, newdatasize, 0);
            cout << GetLastError() << endl;

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `0x1B13B498FB0` is not the correct address. Remember that windows randomizes the address space each run. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Microsoft_Windows)

Comment: I used cheat engine to get the adress and if i change the value in cheat engine it changes in game aswell , i also havent closed the game at all so the adress couldnt have  randomised

Comment: You're calling `GetLastError()` without checking the return value of the function to know if the error is valid. It is not uncommon for functions to change the error value even if they succeed.

Comment: Well it definitely didnt change the value in game so I don’t think it works anyways . Might have missunderstood what you mean tho

Comment: You usually have to `VirtualProtectEx()` the memory you want to modify. It's probably not `PAGE_READWRITE`. Once you do that *then* you modify it. You must remember to change it back to what it *was* when you are done.

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory` returns a value to let you know if it succeeded or not but you're ignoring it. It also provides a mechanism to tell how many bytes were written but you're not using that either. At this point you don't know if it failed or if it succeeded and wrote anything. It might be doing just what you asked but the address is wrong. `VirtualProtectEx` is also a good idea as @Andy mentioned.

Comment: I'll add an example of virtualprotectex

Comment: Well, how about that. I spent many of hours in my life doing it the hard way when all this time I didn't need to do it. Apparently `WriteProcessMemory` handles memory protection for you. So, I have no idea why this is not working :)

Comment: @Andy I somehow found a fix to the problem , i went to configuration manager and changed the platform from Win32 to x64 and somehow that made it work , thanks your your help either way!

Comment: Awesome! -- good feeling when a plan comes together.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me had an easy fix ,but not that easy to find it . I had to go to configuration manager and changed the platform from Win32 to x64 and that made it work